# overlay transparent image onto another image, but keep RGB channels

Tags: python-imaging-library, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to overlay a watermark onto my image, such that the watermark is visible in the R,G,B channels but since the alpha channel is 0, the watermark is not visible on the overall image.

I created the watermark using `convert watermark.png -alpha set -channel a -evaluate set 0% +channel watermark-t.png`

I've spent a lot of time tweaking the following command, trying to use `separate` and `-combine` as well, but I am at my wit's end. Please help!

`magick convert img.png watermark-t.png -gravity North-West -composite img_plus_watermark.png`

When I use the above command, the watermark gets overlaid, but is not visible in any of the (including RGB) layers.

I've also tried using Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("img.png")
watermark = Image.open("watermark-t.png")

r, g, b, a = watermark.split()
watermark = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
mask = Image.merge("L", (a,))
img.paste(watermark, (0, 0), mask)
img.save("img_plus_watermark.png")
```

Still doesn't work.

The closest I came is to mask the img and watermark in the area where the watermark is overlaid. This leaves a transparent chunk of image in that area, but the image and watermark are visible in the RGB layers. I don't want this though.

Are PNGs just not equipped to handle this since they have only one alpha channel? Are there other image formats like TIFFs which contain layers that can do better -- if yes how?

Watermark:

Watermark original
[image: Watermark-original]

Watermark transparent
[image: Watermark-transparent]

Image
[image: img]

img+watermark-masked-to-remove-chunk-of-image
[image: img+watermark-masked-to-remove-chunk-of-image]

img+watermark-opaque
[image: img+watermark-opaque]

img+watermark-transparent (result of the above code)
[image: img+watermark-transparent (result of above code)]

Comment: Post your background image and your watermark image

Comment: The goal is for the image to look exactly as it is, but for the logo to appear in the RGB channels and not in the alpha channel. Does that clarify?

Comment: Also, the logo that needs to go on the final image is fully transparent (I've uploaded it above, but it's not visible, since it's transparent)

Comment: I don't really understand the effect you are trying to achieve. Do you want the rainbow tick to float over the shoe? I think you should post a mockup of the result you need.

Comment: @jcupitt, I want the final shoe+watermark image to look exactly like the image under "img+watermark-transparent" (Notice that there are no visible chunks of the image missing, and the logo is not visible), However, in the R,G,B channels of this shoe+watermark image, I still want to be able to see the watermark. Like Camden's answer below, I wonder if this is not possible, or possible using different image formats, like .TIFF

Comment: So this is like a secret? You want to hide the tick in the transparent parts of the image? That's easy -- remove the alpha, add in your secret RGB, then put the original alpha back on.

Comment: It's a secret, but I want to hide it in the non transparent parts of the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to hide a secret in the transparent parts of an image, that's actually pretty easy: remove the alpha from the image, paste in your solid RGB secret to the RGB parts of some transparent bit of the image, then reattach the original alpha.

For example, here's the standard PNG demo image -- the background is transparent:

[image]

And here's a tiny mario sprite (also an RGBA PNG with a transparent background):

[image]

I can remove the alpha from the demo image and the mario PNG like this (using [libvips](https://www.libvips.org/) because I know it well, but I'm sure it'd be easy in imagemagick too):

```
$ vips extract_band PNG_transparency_demonstration.png bg.png 0 --n 3
$ vips extract_band mario.png fg.png 0 --n 3
```

That's extracting the bands (channels), starting at band 0 (red) and taking three of them (`--n 3`), so just the RGB parts.

Now I can paste mario in:

```
$ vips insert bg.png fg.png final-rgb.png 10 10
```

To make this RGB (no alpha) image:

[image]

Finally, I take the original alpha from the PNG demo and reattach it:

```
$ vips extract_band PNG_transparency_demonstration.png alpha.png 3
$ vips bandjoin "final-rgb.png alpha.png" result.png
```

To make this:

[image]

That looks like the PNG demo image, but it has a secret mario hidden in the top left corner. You need to remove the alpha to see it.

Comment: So *"down wiv da kids"* using Mario 

Comment: @jcupitt, unfortunately the background is not transparent. :(  in this case, i am guessing it's not possible?

Comment: You'd need to make the shoe background transparent, yes. It wouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: Sure, but for images with coloured backgrounds you wouldn't be able to see it right?

Comment: PNG lets you set a background colour, would that help? The transparent parts would become solid #aabbcc. Though plenty of PNG renderers ignore the bg colour setting, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your issue. Just do the following in Imagemagick:

```
convert shoe.png \( watermark.png -alpha off \) -compose over -composite result.png
```

[image]

If this is not what you want, then please clarify further.

**ADDITION**

If you want the result to be transparent, but the watermark in the RGB channels, then you can use MPR: in memory storage to help to do that. It is like a named clone that can be used later by name.

```
convert shoe.png \( watermark.png -write mpr:img -alpha off \) \
-compose over -composite \( mpr:img -alpha extract \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result2.png
```

[image]

```
convert result2.png -alpha off rgb.png
```

[image]

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#mpr

Comment: Thanks @fmw42! After the logo is embedded, I still want the image to look like the image under `img+watermark-transparent (result of the above code)`. However, I want the logo to still be visible in the R, G, B channels (just not in the overall image). is this even possible?

Comment: Thanks @fmw42. Sorry this is complicated, and there's lots of back and forth. I want the image to be visible but the watermark to be transparent. So, the final result (after the watermark is overlaid) looks like the shoe image under "Image" in the question, but I am hoping to see the watermark in the R, G, B channels. Can MPR allow me to do that?

Further, when I run your MPR commands, I don't get a transparent image for result2, I get the full RGB image.

Comment: There is no way to overlay the watermark, such that the alpha channel is off and you don't see the watermark. If you overlay the watermark, it must be visible in the RGB channels whether the alpha channel is on or off.  If I misunderstand, then please clarify further. In my example, I posted two images. The first was totally transparent, but the watermark was overlayed in the RGB channels. The second image just turned off the alpha so that you could see that the watermark was there in the RGB channels. What is your Imagemagick version and platform?

Comment: Thanks yeah, this was my suspicion. Is this possible with certain image formats like TIFFs? My magick version is 7.0.10-29, and I am on an Ubuntu derivative (22.04)

Comment: As I understand your question, it is not possible with any format.  You cannot have the overlay in the RGB channels without it showing unless you encrypt it. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#encipher. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be helpful, but thank you so much for your care, and time!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the watermark behind the image. Standard PNG images only contain one of each color band and one optional Alpha band (R, G, B, & A). So, there cannot be two RGBA values for any given pixel. In other words, when combining two PNGs the RGBA values of one image overwrite the other.

The alpha band (A) records the opacity of the RGB values in the image. So, you could set the alpha values of the watermark to 0 and add it to the image making it invisible (similar to what you've already done - see below).

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("shoe.png")
watermark = Image.open("watermark-t.png")
watermark.putalpha(0)
img.paste(watermark)
img.save("img2.png")
```

Output:
[image: img2.png]

You'll notice the top left corner is transparent and if the background was transparent too it would blend in but not in this case because it is white.

The code below will increase the alpha values of the image to show the watermark is still in the image.

```
from PIL import Image
img2 = Image.open("img2.png")
img2.putalpha(1000)
img2.save("img3.png")
```

Output:
[image: img3.png]

### Edit

**Per your comment about the possibility of using tiff images:**

I used the `gdal` library to generate a '7-band' tiff file that holds the color data for the watermark but does not display it (With the caveat that the watermark not being displayed may be dependent on the application used for displaying the image and the extra bands may cause some applications to be unable to read the image). I will add, this isn't the most efficient way to accomplish this but hopefully it is fairly clear.

*If using Windows and installing `gdal` I would recommend downloading the wheel file of the library and using `pip install <path to whl>`.*

```
from PIL import Image
from osgeo import gdal
# Convert shoe image from RGBA png to RGBA tif
img = Image.open("shoe.png")
img.save("shoe2.tif")
# Open the images
src_ds = gdal.OpenShared("shoe2.tif")
water_ds = gdal.OpenShared("watermark-t.png")
# Create memory copy of shoe tif
tmp_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').CreateCopy('', src_ds, 0)
# loop 1,2,3 for gdal syntax when using GetRasterBand
for i in range(1,4):
    # Get watermark RGB bands as arrays
    wband = water_ds.GetRasterBand(i).ReadAsArray()
    # Add 5,6,7 bands to tif
    tmp_ds.AddBand()
    # Write RGB data to 5,6,7 bands of tif (4 is for Alpha)
    tmp_ds.GetRasterBand(i + 4).WriteArray(wband)
# Save as tif
dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').CreateCopy("img3.tif", tmp_ds, 0)
# Clean up
del src_ds
del water_ds
del tmp_ds
del dst_ds
```

The output (`img3.tif`) looks the same as `shoe.png`. Unfortunately it is too large to upload here (~14mb). To prove the watermark data is still intact in the tif the following code will take the 5, 6, & 7 bands and output them in a png.

```
from PIL import Image
from osgeo import gdal
# Create an empty png to store data in, size reflects the shoe image now
new_watermark = Image.new("RGB", (1938,1090))
new_watermark.save("empty.png")

img3_ds = gdal.OpenShared("img3.tif")
png_ds = gdal.OpenShared("empty.png")
water2_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName("MEM").CreateCopy("", png_ds, 0)
for i in range(1,4):
    band = img3_ds.GetRasterBand(i + 4).ReadAsArray()
    water2_ds.GetRasterBand(i).WriteArray(band)
output_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName("PNG").CreateCopy("remake_watermark.png", water2_ds, 0)
del img3_ds
del water2_ds
del output_ds
```

Output:
[image: remake_watermark.png]

Comment: thanks! This is what I suspected. Can something like this be done if you use another image format like a TIFF file, which allows layers?

Comment: I apologize for my delayed responses. Multipage tiff files can hold multiple images (sometimes called; subfiles, frames, or layers) but they are able to rotate through the images like a gif but manual. You could potentially do this by redefining the RGB values of the watermark to different bands. This would result in a multispectral tiff with at least 6 bands (or 6 samples per pixel). Alternatively, you could embed one image inside of another where it cannot be displayed (similar to steganography).

Comment: thank you! I am hoping to create this image in a way that fools a human but doesn't fool an image classifier. What's the process to create a multispectral tiff file? Images with steganography don't seem to fool classifiers.

Comment: @user81371 See my updated answer on how to do this.